# Let Lua call the host program?

Tags: lua, ffi

I'm really tired of making so many wrappers for every function which needs to be used in the scripts. I noticed [this Lua FFI tutorial](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html). I hope that I could use FFI to call the host program directly. Is this possible? If possible, how to do it?

Comment: Using an FFI as your scripting interface is going to make the Lua very non-idiomatic/ugly. I prefer to hand-code interfaces, but at the very least you could use some kind of [binding tool](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing the ffi specifications by hand you could use Swig to automate the task: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html